# How to frame a question, where speaker knows the answer still asking for it?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The Pin knows Brendan's location but still asking Brendan for it.

I want to phrase the sentence in question format, asking why The Pin still asking it?

Comment: Why is the Pin asking for Brendan's location when he already knows it?

Comment: Do not assume that anyone has seen the obscure movie you seem to be asking about. We have no way to know who or what "The Pin" is.

Comment: The Pin is character name & proper noun.

Comment: Luke has answered your question anyway.

Comment: @LukeSawczak The Pin is asking **Brendan** also? you didn't mention it in your comment.

Comment: Why is the Pin asking Brendan for his location when he already knows it?

Answer (score 1):

A few idiomatic question structures would be:

> **Why is the Pin asking for his location? He already knows it!**

Or,

> **The Pin knows his location; why is he asking?**

Also,

> **Why is the Pin asking if he already knows his location?**